# Force browser to use cached pages

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, cache

The move to https effectively killed any meaning for the browser cache. It literary does nothing but waste life on SSD drives now, since every developer thinks all pages in the universe must expire in the past.

I want my browser to ignore what the http header says and always cache things, unless I refresh a page.

Is this possible? I can change browsers for this so not limiting to a single one.

I already tried in firefox changing `browser.cache.check_doc_frequency` to `2` but it does nothing. In fact, even setting the browser to offline mode (firefox and chrome) fails to use the cache for pages wrongly marked as expired by overzealous developers.

Test i would want to pass:

1. open tab. (e.g. the logged out view of this very question)
2. disconnect computer
3. close tab.
4. reopen closed tab.

expected: see content

what happens: browser tries to reload page because cached page is invalid from the start and only shows me it "cannot reach server" and no content.

I do not care about side effects of this, like breaking sites etc. And certainly I do not care about the original reason browsers implemented no-cache for https pages which was security on OSes that had no security for multi user workstations.